# ошибка Сервер не найден на NGINX на centos 7

Tags: nginx, centos

Запустил NGINX на centos 7.

По ip и [http://сайт.ру](http://xn--80aswg.xn--p1ag) заходит на сайт, а когда [www.сайтр.ру](http://www.xn--80asvbh.xn--p1ag) пишет Сервер не найден

Comment: Вопрос в чем? сейчас это констатация факта и без подробностей...

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, вероятно, вопрос в том, в чём может быть ошибка, какие конфиги и т.п.

Comment: @SergeyK. Вероятно я уже знаю где именно ошибка, но писать конфиг с нуля чтоб помочь очень ленивому человеку(а иначе какие причины отсутствия информации в вопросе?) - ну нет, увольте, а просто скопировать один из его роутов и дописать алиас - не так то и долго

Comment: Сервер не найден скорее показывает на отсутствие DNS для `www.сайт.ру`

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, предложите дополнить вопрос нужной информацией) Человек, по-видимому, совсем недавно тут